# How would I best use componentsSeparatedByCharacterSet but keep the separator/delimiter attached to the first word?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, nsarray

Say I have the following sentence:

> I am a sentence that has hyphenated-words at some-points in it.

And I have the following code:

```
NSCharacterSet *separators = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" -"];
NSArray *sentenceArray = [sentence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:separators];
```

That separates the string into an array, separated at spaces and hyphens. The resulting array is:

> ["I", "am", "a", "sentence", "that", "has", "hyphenated", "words", "at", "some", "points", "in", "it."]

Which, as you can see, does its job, but *now I don't know which words were initially hyphenated*. What I'd really love is something like

> [ ... "has-", "hyphenated", ... ]

Where it appends the first string with the separating character. But just for hyphens.

But I realize this seems difficult. How would I best go about figuring out which parts were separated due to hyphenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing `'-'` with `'- '` like this:

```
NSCharacterSet *separators = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "];
sentence = [sentence stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"- "];
NSArray *sentenceArray = [sentence componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: separators];
```